# SpringApplication.run main method

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-boot

I created a project in Eclipse using the Spring Starter project template.

It automatically created an Application class file, and that path matches the path in the POM.xml file, so all is well. Here is the Application class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //SpringApplication.run(ReconTool.class, args);  
        ReconTool.main(args);
    }
}
```

This is a command line app that I am building and in order to get it to run I had to comment out the SpringApplication.run line and just add the main method from my other class to run.
Other than this quick jerry-rig, I can build it using Maven and it runs as a Spring application, sort of.

I'd rather, however, not have to comment out that line, and use the full Spring framework. How can I do this?

Comment: you mean you want to launch this app by maven instead of launching from IDE ?

Comment: Your ReconTool is Spring application? Or maybe plain Java application?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You need to run `SpringApplication.run()` because this method starts whole Spring Framework. Code below integrates your `main()` with Spring Boot.

### `Application.java`

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

### `ReconTool.java`

```
@Component
public class ReconTool implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        main(args);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Recon Logic
    }
}
```

## Why not `SpringApplication.run(ReconTool.class, args)`

Because this way spring is not fully configured (no component scan etc.). Only bean defined in run() is created (ReconTool).

Example project: https://github.com/mariuszs/spring-run-magic

Comment: I think you meant:  SpringApplication.run(ReconTool.class, args);

Comment: No, `RecontTool` has `@Component` added, so spring will execute `RecontTool.run()` and `RecontTool.main()` ofcourse :)

Comment: But you are true, `SpringApplication.run(ReconTool.class, args)` works too :)

Comment: I would rather leave `SpringApplication.run(Application.class` because this works, second solution looks too magic to me :)

Comment: Your solution works without `@Component` :) https://github.com/mariuszs/spring-run-magic

Comment: Nowadays, you could replace `@Configuration`, `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and use `@SpringBootApplication` instead

Comment: I do not understand why the ```Foo``` constructor does not get run. Class ```Foo```  is in the same package as ```ReconTool``` and ```@SpringBootApplication``` does the component scan from that package thus ```Foo``` should be scanned for bean generation, right? I got this understanding from the link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning: ```@ComponentScan without arguments tells Spring to scan the current package and all of its sub-packages.```

Answer (score 20):

Using:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);  

        //do your ReconTool stuff
    }
}
```

will work in all circumstances. Whether you want to launch the application from the IDE, or the build tool.

Using maven just use `mvn spring-boot:run`

while in gradle it would be `gradle bootRun`

An alternative to adding code under the run method, is to have a Spring Bean that implements `CommandLineRunner`. That would look like:

```
@Component
public class ReconTool implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       //implement your business logic here
    }
}
```

Check out [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) guide from Spring's official guide repository.

The full Spring Boot documentation can be found [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-documentation)

Comment: You steal all my ideas :)

Comment: It seams like we are thinking in parallel :)

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to extend the application (as my application was to inherit and customize the parent). It invokes the parent and its commandlinerunner automatically.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ChildApplication extends ParentApplication{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ChildApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```