# spring service is not autowired in main class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired

Here is my SourceRepository class which does not override the autogenerated general findAll() which returns Iterable

```
package com.infostream.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;

import com.infostream.models.Source;

public interface SourceRepositoryImpl extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Source, Long>{

    Page<Source> findAll(Pageable pageRequest);

}
```

Here is my service class:

```
package com.infostream.services;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.infostream.models.Source;
import com.infostream.repositories.SourceRepositoryImpl;

@Component
public class SourcesService {
    @Autowired
    private SourceRepositoryImpl sourceRepository;

    public PageImpl<Source> getPaginatedSources(Pageable pageRequest) {
        Page<Source> searchResultPage = sourceRepository.findAll(pageRequest);
        return new PageImpl<Source>(searchResultPage.getContent(), pageRequest, searchResultPage.getTotalElements()); 
    }

    public Iterable<Source> getAllSources() {
        return sourceRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Here is my main class which i run as a Java application.

```
package com.infostream.services;

import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.infostream.consumers.RssArticleConsumer;
import com.infostream.models.Article;
import com.infostream.models.Source;
import com.infostream.producers.RssXmlProducer;

public class HarvestService {

    private static BlockingQueue<Article> article_queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Article>(10);

    @Autowired
    private static SourcesService sourcesService;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Iterable<Source> sources = sourcesService.getAllSources();

        /*
        for(Source s : sources) {
            System.out.println(s.getUrl());
        }

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new RssXmlProducer(sources.iterator().next(), article_queue));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new RssArticleConsumer(article_queue));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        */      
    }


}
```

The sourcesService variable is null, i see the Autowiring is not working but i do not know why. Is it because i am running the HarvestService file as a Java Application by right clicking on the file in the package explorer and clicking run as java application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using spring boot? 
looks like your HarvestService class needs `@SpringBootApplication` and add thid in main function

```
SpringApplication.run(HarvestService.class, args);
```

and make sure you have the right dependency in your maven/gradle.
hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that did not work for me. essentially what i am trying to achieve is to be able to run my service classes using the command line and run only the rest_controller part of the application using spring boot

Comment: yes thats why u need the `@SpringBootApplication` and if you want to run using command line implement the `CommandLineRunner` and override the run method. put your code inside run method and test using `mvn package` then `java -jar target/harvest.jar`

Comment: oh i see, i will try that next, but i am having some compiler missing steps when i run mvn package, will get back to you once i fix these issues

Comment: ok thanks, this helped me out, i ended up using this link and turned my service into a component because running it as a separate SpringBootApplication was not working for me, maybe it is because how my modules are set up or something else i used this link to run it as a component and it ran when i ran the rest app https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/spring-boot/how-to-use-commandlinerunner-in-spring-boot-application.html

Comment: delete the static keyword from the field that you injected the beans, use the CommandLineRunner interface and after adding SpringApplication.run(HarvestService.class, args) and @SpringBootApplication, use the beans in the run(String... args) method.

Answer (score 5):

i had the same problem also, `@Autowired` was not working in the main class
What i did was to get a reference to the `ApplicationContext`, then use it to get the `sourcesService` as a bean

have rewrote your class as below

```
package com.infostream.services;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
// adedd import file
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import com.infostream.consumers.RssArticleConsumer;
import com.infostream.models.Article;
import com.infostream.models.Source;
import com.infostream.producers.RssXmlProducer;

@SpringBootApplication // added this here
public class HarvestService 
{
    private static BlockingQueue<Article> article_queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Article>(10);

    @Autowired
    private static SourcesService sourcesService;

    ApplicationContext context; // added this here


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // added this - get reference to application context
        context = SpringApplication.run(HarvestService.class, args);
        // added this - get the object via the context as a bean
        sourcesService = (SourcesService) context.getBean("sourcesService");


        Iterable<Source> sources = sourcesService.getAllSources();

        /*
        for(Source s : sources) {
            System.out.println(s.getUrl());
        }

        Thread t1 = new Thread(new RssXmlProducer(sources.iterator().next(),article_queue));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new RssArticleConsumer(article_queue));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        */      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement CommandLineRunner and put your code inside the method run, because spring need to load all the components and with the normal main it is not going to work

```
@Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        main(args);
    }
```

[SpringApplication.run main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271705/springapplication-run-main-method)

Answer (score 0):

Used modelmapper dependency (2.4.4) .Use @RequiredArgsConstructor and modelmapper method with @Bean annotation on main class. The bean that to be initialize should be final.