# Springboot : startup issue(missing ServletWebServerFactory bean)

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have added the annotation on main class,given below:

```
package com.main;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;

import com.controller.RequestClass;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan("com.*")
public class MainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(RequestClass.class, args);
    }
}
```

but on running the application , facing below error.

please let me know if require any other file to debug

> 2018-07-08 14:16:27.321  INFO 7832 --- [           main]
>   com.main.MainClass                       : Starting MainClass on
>   DESKTOP-551C51M with PID 7832
>   (C:\Users\sparsh\eclipse-workspace\firstprogram\target\classes started
>   by sparsh in C:\Users\sparsh\eclipse-workspace\firstprogram)
>   2018-07-08 14:16:27.327  INFO 7832 --- [           main]
>   com.main.MainClass                       : No active profile set,
>   falling back to default profiles: default 2018-07-08 14:16:27.382 
>   INFO 7832 --- [           main]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@2893de87:
>   startup date [Sun Jul 08 14:16:27 IST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
>   2018-07-08 14:16:27.611  WARN 7832 --- [           main]
>   ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing
>   ServletWebServerFactory bean. 2018-07-08 14:16:27.974 ERROR 7832 --- [
>   main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run
>   failed
>
> org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start web server; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing
>   ServletWebServerFactory bean.     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]     at
>   com.main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:21) [classes/:na] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to
>   start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing
>   ServletWebServerFactory bean.     at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:204)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:178)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]    ... 8 common frames
>   omitted

Comment: can you post pom.xml ?

Comment: below answer solved it bro, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens if springapplicatiom.run is against the main class not the controller class - does it start ? Take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/44466367/5126865 (am assuming a bit about what you want to achieve so apologies if off the mark)