# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invokeController.addFlight()" because Controller is null

Tags: java, spring, nullpointerexception, logic

I am Facing a null pointer Exception. can you please help me Explain what is the actual issue and what I am doing wrong. Pardon for Crude Coding as I am beginner.

This is the error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.org.Controller.Controller.addFlight()" because "com.org.App.controller" is null
at com.org.App.main(App.java:22)

This are the classes:

**App**

```
package com.org;

import com.org.Config.AppConfig;
import com.org.Controller.Controller;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

    @Autowired
    public static Controller controller;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to AirGO Airline");
            System.out.println("Please chose what you would like to do");
            System.out.println("1.Add Flight:");
            System.out.println("2.Search Flight");
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
            Integer userChoice= scanner.nextInt();
            if (1==userChoice){
                controller.addFlight();
            } else if (2==userChoice) {
                controller.showFlight();
            }
            else
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Valid Input");
        }
}
```

**Controller**     //A fake controller class

```
package com.org.Controller;

import com.org.Config.AppConfig;
import com.org.Domain.Flight;
import com.org.Service.FlightServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


import java.time.LocalDate;
@Component
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    FlightServiceImpl flightService= new FlightServiceImpl();
    public void addFlight(){
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Flight flight=new Flight();
        flight.setAirlines("Indigo");
        flight.setSource("India");
        flight.setDestination("Japan");
        flight.setFare(50456.54);
        LocalDate date= LocalDate.now();
        flight.setJourneyDate(date);
        flight.setSeatCount(2);
        flightService.addFlight(flight);
    }

    public void showFlight(){
        ApplicationContext applicationContext= new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        FlightServiceImpl flightService= applicationContext.getBean(FlightServiceImpl.class);
        LocalDate date= LocalDate.now();
//not complete
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
package com.org.Service;

import com.org.Domain.Flight;
import com.org.Repository.FlightRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class FlightServiceImpl implements FlightService{

    @Autowired
    FlightRepositoryImpl flightRepository;


    @Override
    public void addFlight(Flight flight) {
        try{
            flightRepository.addFlight(flight);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Flight Insertion Unsuccessful, Cannot connect to Database....");
        }

    }
}
```

**CONFIG CLASS**

```
package com.org.Config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.org")
public class AppConfig {
    //Beans AutoGenerated
}
```

**DOMAIN CLASS**

```
package com.org.Domain;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Flight {
    private String flightId;
    private String airlines;
    private String source;
    private String destination;
    private double fare;
    private LocalDate journeyDate;
    private Integer seatCount;

    public Flight() {
    }

    public String getFlightId() {
        return flightId;
    }

    public void setFlightId(String flightId) {
        this.flightId = flightId;
    }

    public String getAirlines() {
        return airlines;
    }

    public void setAirlines(String airlines) {
        this.airlines = airlines;
    }

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public String getDestination() {
        return destination;
    }

    public void setDestination(String destination) {
        this.destination = destination;
    }

    public double getFare() {
        return fare;
    }

    public void setFare(double fare) {
        this.fare = fare;
    }

    public LocalDate getJourneyDate() {
        return journeyDate;
    }

    public void setJourneyDate(LocalDate journeyDate) {
        this.journeyDate = journeyDate;
    }

    public Integer getSeatCount() {
        return seatCount;
    }

    public void setSeatCount(Integer seatCount) {
        this.seatCount = seatCount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Flight{" +
                "flightId='" + flightId + '\'' +
                ", airlines='" + airlines + '\'' +
                ", source='" + source + '\'' +
                ", destination='" + destination + '\'' +
                ", fare=" + fare +
                ", journeyDate=" + journeyDate +
                ", seatCount=" + seatCount +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**REPOSITRY**

```
package com.org.Repository;

import com.org.Domain.Flight;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Repository
public class FlightRepositoryImpl implements FlightRepository{

    private static Integer flightId = 1000;
    @Override
    public void addFlight(Flight flight) {
        Map<Integer, Flight> database= new HashMap<Integer, Flight>();
        flightId+=1;
        database.put(flightId,flight);
        System.out.println("Added flight details are: "+ flight.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works but Could you please Explain how this is affecting like when i don't create instance using new Operator.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SpringApplication.run main method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24271705/springapplication-run-main-method)

Answer (score 1):

Update you config class as below.

```java
package com.org.Config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.org")
public class AppConfig {
    //Beans AutoGenerated

    @Bean
    public Controller controller() {
       return new Controller();
    }
}
```

But in ideal world scenario. The controller class should be annotated with `@RestController` or `@Controller` and mapped to correct http endpoint mappings.

Hope this helps.

Update:
Also your App class missing `@SpringBootApplication` if you are using Spring-Boot or `@Component` if using Spring. Update your class as per the usecase.

Spring Boot:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    @Autowired
    public static Controller controller;

        public static void main(String[] args) { 
           SpringApplication.run(args, App.class);
        }
}
```

Spring:

```java
@Component
public class App {

    public static Controller controller;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
            controller = context.getBean(Controller.class);
            System.out.println("Hello, Welcome to AirGO Airline");
            System.out.println("Please chose what you would like to do");
            System.out.println("1.Add Flight:");
            System.out.println("2.Search Flight");
            Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
            Integer userChoice= scanner.nextInt();
            if (1==userChoice){
                controller.addFlight();
            } else if (2==userChoice) {
                controller.showFlight();
            }
            else
            System.out.println("Please Enter a Valid Input");
        }
}
```

I think I would prefer Spring Boot way. If you want further help on the command line baased application create a repository on GitHub with code from example and share it here we can discuss and contribute.

Comment: I updated the same and also tried using "@Component" since i am using "@ComponentScan" but the issue still persists.

edit: it's working after creating a new instance of Controller class in App class. 
Thanks

Comment: The actual problem here is that this application is started using a regular `main` that doesn't involve springboot and thus has no active dependency injection mechanism. Therefore, no autowiring can happen.